# Postgres array value must starts

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I want to make an array and put into it two id's, but I got a mistake:

> array value must start with “{” or dimension information

```
ids_list character varying[] := ' || (SELECT COALESCE(quote_literal((array_agg(DISTINCT house_guid)) || ''',''' || quote_literal(array_agg(DISTINCT guid))), 'NULL') FROM tb) || ';
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_agg` function

```
with t1 as 
(
select * from 
(
select 'test_SQL_01' as ID
union
select 'test_SQL_02_PQR_01'
union
select 'test_SQL_03_055'
union
select 'test_SQL_04_ABC_99'
) as t
) select array_agg(ID) from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using this inside a PL/pgSQL function. You should be using `SELECT ... INTO variable FROM...` instead:

```
declare
  ids_list character varying[];
begin
  ..... 
  select array_agg(id)
    into ids_list
  from (
    select house_guid
    from tab
    union 
    select guid
    from tab
  ) t;

  .... work with the ids_list variable
end;
```

The `UNION` will automatically remove all duplicates (as you tried to do with `DISTINCT`.